Robot framework : Drag and Drop is not working in firefox
I'm using the drag and drop keyword. When I run the test on Chrome, it works—the element is being dragged and dropped. However, when I run the test in Firefox, the test passes but the drag and drop action is not working. Can someone help me, please?
dragElement = 'css=tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(1)'
dropElement = 'css=tbody tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(1)'

enter image description here
I tried to run the test in Chrome, and it is working. However, in Firefox, it is not.
